# How can I pass a mailing list to a mail job?

Tags: pentaho

I get a mail list from a SQL query as a string ('xxx@gmail.com, yyyy@gmail.com'), but when I pass that variable to Job Mail Function, it doesn't recognize as a list but as an email address. I tried to make a transformation to a field with different values (each row is address), but the variable only accepts one value, so I get an error.

I tried passing address list as string

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses are space separated, not comma separated. Replace those commas by spaces and it should work.